# Visual Studio 2015 - Xamarin Studio 2.2 Connection to the layout renderer failed

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to create a Cross Platform application for a Android and iOS but I can't get by this error.

*Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of of Java.*

I followed the Xamarin installation guide and various solutions on Xamarin forms and have not been able to resolve this issue. I installed Visual Studio Professional and downloaded Xamarin Studio 2.2 a week ago hoping to dive into mobile development but I'm stuck with this issue.  I have successfully connected to a Mac Mini and can deploy without any issues. Does anyone have a solid solution on resolving this issue. I tried installing/uninstalling/reinstalling combinations jdk 1.7 32-bit and jdk 1.8 64-bit. I also tried reinstalling Xamarin Studio as well the Android SDK.  Any help will be appreciated.

Current software installed:
Windows 10 Home 64-bit
Visual Studio Professional 2015 v14.0.25431.01
Android Studio 2.2
JDK 1.8.0.101

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

I believe I fixed this error. I've been banging my forehead on my laptop for the past week but I appear to have stumbled across a solution. I noticed my Android SDK Manager was not coming up so I started investigating this issue and I ended up pointing the location Android SDK in VS2015 to a different location. I really don't have a solid understanding of structure of Xamarin and VS2015 so I can't really explain the reasoning why this appears to have worked. But here is what I ended up doing.

**Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location**

Old location:
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK

New location:
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

The only thing I notice was that the "Old location" was missing the "SDK Manager.exe" and "AVD Manager.exe" files but the new location had these two files. This also resolved my Android SDK Manager issue. Hope this helps someone else that might be running into this issue and if someone can explain why this may have worked I'll be more than interested in hearing it.

(I also tried copying the two missing *.exe files to the "Old location and that did not work.)